# How to rotate seaborn barplot x-axis tick labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, xticks

I'm trying to get a barplot to rotate it's X Labels in 45° to make them readable (as is, there's overlap).

`len(genero)` is 7, and `len(filmes_por_genero)` is 20

I'm using a MovieLens dataset and making a graph counting the number of movies in each individual genre. Here's my code as of now:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set_style("whitegrid")

filmes_por_genero = filmes["generos"].str.get_dummies('|').sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
genero = filmes_com_media.index

chart = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
sns.barplot(x=genero,
            y=filmes_por_genero.values,
            palette=sns.color_palette("BuGn_r", n_colors=len(filmes_por_genero) + 4)
            )

chart.set_xticklabels(
    chart.get_xticklabels(), 
    rotation=45, 
    horizontalalignment='right'
)
```

Here's the full error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py in get_grouper(obj, key, axis, level, sort, observed, mutated, validate)
    623                 in_axis=in_axis,
    624             )
--> 625             if not isinstance(gpr, Grouping)
    626             else gpr
    627         )

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py in __init__(self, index, grouper, obj, name, level, sort, observed, in_axis)
    254         self.name = name
    255         self.level = level
--> 256         self.grouper = _convert_grouper(index, grouper)
    257         self.all_grouper = None
    258         self.index = index

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py in _convert_grouper(axis, grouper)
    653     elif isinstance(grouper, (list, Series, Index, np.ndarray)):
    654         if len(grouper) != len(axis):
--> 655             raise ValueError("Grouper and axis must be same length")
    656         return grouper
    657     else:

ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

- Data from [MovieLens 25M Dataset](http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-25m.zip) at [MovieLens](https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/)
- The following code uses the [explicit `Axes` interface](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/figure/api_interfaces.html#the-explicit-axes-interface) with the seaborn [axes-level functions](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions).

  - See [How to rotate xticklabels in a seaborn catplot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63912211/7758804) for the [figure-level functions](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions).
- If there's no need to change the `xticklabels`, the easiest option is [`ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html), but `horizontalalignment` / `ha` can't be set.

  - [`ax.set_xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html) can be used with [`ax.get_xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticks.html) and [`ax.get_xticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticklabels.html)
  - [`ax.set_xticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html) works with [`ax.get_xticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticklabels.html), but results in `UserWarning: set_ticklabels() should only be used with a fixed number of ticks, i.e. after set_ticks() or using a FixedLocator.`

    - Becasue `sns.barplot` is a categorical plot, and `native_scale=False` by default, the xticks are 0 indexed, so the xticklabels can be set, and the warning ignored.
- **Tested in `python v3.12.0`, `pandas v2.1.2`, `matplotlib v3.8.1`, `seaborn v0.13.0`.**

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# data
df = pd.read_csv('ml-25m/movies.csv')

print(df.head())

   movieId                               title                                       genres
0        1                    Toy Story (1995)  Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy
1        2                      Jumanji (1995)                   Adventure|Children|Fantasy
2        3             Grumpier Old Men (1995)                               Comedy|Romance
3        4            Waiting to Exhale (1995)                         Comedy|Drama|Romance
4        5  Father of the Bride Part II (1995)                                       Comedy

# split the strings in the genres column
df['genres'] = df['genres'].str.split('|')

# explode the lists that result for str.split
df = df.explode('genres', ignore_index=True)

print(df.head())

   movieId             title     genres
0        1  Toy Story (1995)  Adventure
1        1  Toy Story (1995)  Animation
2        1  Toy Story (1995)   Children
3        1  Toy Story (1995)     Comedy
4        1  Toy Story (1995)    Fantasy
```

### Genres Counts

```py
gc = df.genres.value_counts().reset_index()

print(gc)

                genres  count
0                Drama  25606
1               Comedy  16870
2             Thriller   8654
3              Romance   7719
4               Action   7348
5               Horror   5989
6          Documentary   5605
7                Crime   5319
8   (no genres listed)   5062
9            Adventure   4145
10              Sci-Fi   3595
11            Children   2935
12           Animation   2929
13             Mystery   2925
14             Fantasy   2731
15                 War   1874
16             Western   1399
17             Musical   1054
18           Film-Noir    353
19                IMAX    195
```

### [`sns.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html)

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
sns.barplot(data=gc, x='genres', y='count', hue='genres', palette=sns.color_palette("BuGn_r", n_colors=len(gc)), ec='k', legend=False, ax=ax)

ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45)
# ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='right')
# ax.set_xticks(ticks=ax.get_xticks(), labels=ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='right')
plt.show()
```

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
ax = sns.barplot(data=gc, x='genres', y='count', hue='genres', palette=sns.color_palette("BuGn_r", n_colors=len(gc)), ec='k', legend=False)

ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45)
# ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='right')
# ax.set_xticks(ticks=ax.get_xticks(), labels=ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='right')
plt.show()
```

[image]

### [`sns.countplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html)

- Use `sns.countplot` to skip using `.value_counts()` if the plot order doesn't matter.
- To order the `countplot`, `order=df.genres.value_counts().index` must be used, so `countplot` doesn't really save you from needing `.value_counts()`, if a descending order is desired.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
sns.countplot(data=df, x='genres', ax=ax)

ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45)
# ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='right')
# ax.set_xticks(ticks=ax.get_xticks(), labels=ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='right')
plt.show()
```

[image]

### [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

- `.value_counts` can be plotted directly, and the `rot=` parameter can be used to rotate the xticklabels.

```py
ax = df.genres.value_counts().plot(kind='bar', rot=45, width=0.85, ec='k', figsize=(12, 6))
```

---

- In a bar plot with long xticklabels, the cleaner option might be to use horizontal bars.

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
ax = sns.barplot(data=gc, y='genres', x='count', orient='h', hue='genres',
                 palette=sns.color_palette("BuGn_r", n_colors=len(gc)), ec='k', legend=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Shorter code for label rotation:

```
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
```

- Rotates labels by 45 degree
- Aligns labels horizontally to the right for better readability

**Full Example**

`sns.countplot` with sorted x-axis

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = sns.load_dataset('planets')
sns.countplot(data=df,
              x='method',
              order=df['method'].value_counts().index)
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right');
```

[image: countplot]