# How to extract user ratings from a movie dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, data-science, data-scrubbing

This screenshot is the sample of the merged movielens dataset, I have two questions:

1. If I want to extract only user 191 movieid, title, genres and ratings alone, how will I do this?
2. How can I list out **only** the years at the end of each movie title?

Any guide will be highly appreciated.

[image: Screenshot of Movielens Dataset]

Answer (score 2):

First question; Use a Boolean selection

```
df[df['userid']=='191']
```

Second question# Use regex to extract phrases between brackets

```
df['Year']=df.title.str.extract('\((.*?)\)')
```

Comment: Would this return both the phrase and the year that appears in movieid 32 as well?

Comment: What do you mean? Phrase will remain in the column title and my solution creates a new column called Year in which the digit year is input. If extracting year, it cant appear with the phrase again in the same column, can it?

Comment: Oh, so your regex will only return a value if the parenthesis contain only digits? I am not too familiar with regex, but this solution is good!

Comment: The regular expression case works perfectly, but the other solution doesn't produce the expected output. Thanks a lot for the quick response.

Comment: My guess is they're int, not str.

Comment: Is there a reason why you used : `.*?` over something like `\d+` (curious)

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question, you can filter the dataframe.

```
user191 = df.loc[df['userId']==191]
```

For the second part of your question, the year appears to always come at the end, so you can take the last part of the string and remove the parenthesis.

```
df['Year'] = df['title'].str[-5:].str.replace(')','')
```

Answer (score 1):

### Create a dictionary of dataframes for each unique user

- Use a regular expression, `'\((\d+)\)'` to extract the digits, `\d`, from between the parenthesis and assign the value to `movies['Year']`
- Instead of repeatedly filtering the dataframe for different users, this will add each user to a dictionary as the key, and the value will be the dataframe filtered for that user.

  - There are 162541 unique `userId` values, so instead of using `df.userId.unique()`, use a list of the specific `userId` values you're interested in.
- Also see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61371487/7758804) to [How to rotate seaborn barplot x-axis tick labels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61368851/7758804), which is related to this MovieLens dataset.

```py
# question 1: create a column for the year extracted from the title
# extracts the digits between parenthesis
# does not change the title column
df['Year'] = df.title.str.extract('\((\d+)\)')

# create dict of dataframes for each user
userid_movies = dict()
for user in [10, 15, 191]:  # df.userId.unique() = 162541 unique users
    data = df[df.userId == user]
    userid_movies[user] = data

# get data for user 191; assumes ids are int. if not, use '191'
userid_movies[191]  # if you're using jupyter, don't use print
```

### Example

- Given [movie.csv](https://www.kaggle.com/grouplens/movielens-20m-dataset?select=movie.csv) & [rating.csv](https://www.kaggle.com/grouplens/movielens-20m-dataset?select=rating.csv) from [Kaggle: MovieLens 20M Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/grouplens/movielens-20m-dataset)

```
import pandas as pd

# load movies
movies = pd.read_csv('data/ml-25m/movies.csv')

# extract year
movies['Year'] = movies.title.str.extract('\((\d+)\)')

# display head
   movieId                               title                                       genres  Year
0        1                    Toy Story (1995)  Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy  1995
1        2                      Jumanji (1995)                   Adventure|Children|Fantasy  1995
2        3             Grumpier Old Men (1995)                               Comedy|Romance  1995
3        4            Waiting to Exhale (1995)                         Comedy|Drama|Romance  1995
4        5  Father of the Bride Part II (1995)                                       Comedy  1995

# load ratings
ratings = pd.read_csv('data/ml-25m/ratings.csv')

# merge on movieId
df = pd.merge(movies, ratings, on='movieId').reset_index(drop=True)

# display df
   movieId             title                                       genres  Year  userId  rating   timestamp
0        1  Toy Story (1995)  Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy  1995       2     3.5  1141415820
1        1  Toy Story (1995)  Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy  1995       3     4.0  1439472215
2        1  Toy Story (1995)  Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy  1995       4     3.0  1573944252
3        1  Toy Story (1995)  Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy  1995       5     4.0   858625949
4        1  Toy Story (1995)  Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy  1995       8     4.0   890492517

# dict of dataframes
# there are 162541 unique userId values, so instead of using df.userId.unique()
# use a list of the specific Id values you're interested in
userid_movies = dict()
for user in [10, 15, 191]:
    data = df[df.userId == user].reset_index(drop=True)
    userid_movies[user] = data

# display(userid_movies[191].head())
   movieId                                  title                                              genres  Year  userId  rating   timestamp
0    68135                        17 Again (2009)                                        Comedy|Drama  2009     191     3.0  1473704208
1    68791            Terminator Salvation (2009)                    Action|Adventure|Sci-Fi|Thriller  2009     191     5.0  1473704167
2    68954                              Up (2009)                  Adventure|Animation|Children|Drama  2009     191     4.0  1473703994
3    69406                   Proposal, The (2009)                                      Comedy|Romance  2009     191     4.0  1473704198
4    69644  Ice Age: Dawn of the Dinosaurs (2009)  Action|Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Romance  2009     191     1.5  1473704242
```

Comment: what does the timestamp actually means ?

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar Just that, it's a [`timestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp). However, since I posted this answer, the Kaggle file now has a regular datetime stamp. Given the sample in this answer, `df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp, unit='s')` would have converted the column to a `datetime dtype`.

Comment: I meant like what it depicts . As per my understanding , it depicts the time past since the user rated the particular movie  . Am I Right ?

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar yes that’s my understanding

Comment: Thank-you for helping out