# How to rotate x-axis tick lables in Seaborn scatterplot using subplots

Tags: python, seaborn, axes

How can I rotate the x-axis tick labels in a Seaborn scatterplot that is plotted using subplots?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_context("talk", font_scale=1.4) 
  
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['aaaaaaa','bbbbbb1','bbbbbb2','ccccc','dddddd','eeeee'],
                   'y': [7,2,5,8,3,7],
                   'cat': ['X','Y','Y','X','Z','X']
                  })
display(df)
```

[image]

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, figsize=(8,4),
                               gridspec_kw=dict(width_ratios=[2, 1]),
                              )

g1 = sns.scatterplot(data=df,
                    x='id', y='y', hue='cat',
                    s=200, ax=ax1, legend=False,
                   )

g2 = sns.histplot(data=df, y='y', 
                  hue='cat', ax=ax2, binwidth=2, 
                  multiple='stack', legend=False,
                 )
```

[image]

I have tried the following without any success:

1. `g1.xticks(rotation = 90)` and `ax1.xticks(rotation = 90)` both return 
    `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'xticks'`
2. `g1.set_xticklabels(g1.get_xticklabels(), rotation = 90)` based on the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61368851/how-to-rotate-seaborn-barplot-x-axis-tick-labels), but this removes all the tick labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason it looks like the labels are lost in the Seaborn-Matplotlib ether.

```
labels = [item.get_text() for item in g1.get_xticklabels()]
print(labels)
```

returns a list of blanks: `['', '', '', '', '', '']`

So I must remake the labels: `g1.set_xticklabels(df['id'].tolist(), rotation = 90)`

And confirming it works:

```
labels2 = [item.get_text() for item in g1.get_xticklabels()]
print(labels2)
>>['aaaaaaa', 'bbbbbb1', 'bbbbbb2', 'ccccc', 'dddddd', 'eeeee']
```

[image]