# Rotate the xlabels with seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot

I've made a boxplot, but as you see the xlabels are too long so I need to rotate them a little bit:

[image]

I've found several topics for this, here on stack, and on other sites. Some of my tries and the errors I got:

`long_box.set_xticklabels(long_box.get_xticklabels(),rotation=30)`

or

`plt.setp(long_box.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)`

give this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Text' object has no attribute 'set_xticklabels'
```

and, this code `long_box.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)`

produces this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Text' object has no attribute 'tick_params'
```

I didn't understand what does a 'Text' object mean.. how do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried `plt.xticks(rotation=45)` ? Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540035/rotate-label-text-in-seaborn-factorplot) post is useful.

Comment: With `ax = sns.boxplot(...)`, you can use `ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `plt.xticks(rotation=45)` after you define the graph?

In addition to that have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61368851/how-to-rotate-seaborn-barplot-x-axis-tick-labels) since there are a lot of tips on how to do that.